# trouble using distinct() and filter() in django with an Oracle backend

Tags: django, oracle, orm

I'm trying to get a list of all the distinct values field B can take given a value for field A.  I'm using django 1.10 and Oracle 12g.

I tried `MyModel.objects.filter(fieldA='foo').values_list('fieldB').distinct()` but this gives me a list with many duplicates, as if `distinct()` simply isn't working. I can get rid of the duplicates by converting the list to a set in python, but I'd like to rely on the database.

thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 3):

You should use `order_by` in conjunction with `distinct` to get distinct values

```
MyModel.objects.filter(fieldA='foo').order_by('fieldB').values_list('fieldB', flat=True).distinct()
```